# Cross-repo branch policy administration permission?

Tags: azure-devops

Which of the Repos permissions grant the ability to set cross-repo branch policies? If I look at Organization Settings > Security Permissions..Do I need `Administer shelved changes` or `Administer workspaces`?

I'm already a member of  `Project Collection Build Administrators`, but I am not given the ability to add cross-repo branch policies. I want to know exactly which permission is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to be an admin of this project to add cross-repo branch policies. You need to be added to **Project Administrators** group. You can check the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2019/repos/sprint-160-update#cross-repo-branch-policy-administration).

You can have some user who is in the **Project Administrators** group follow below steps to add you to this group.

**Project settings** --> **Permissions** under **General**---> **Project Administrators** --> **Members**-- **Add**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I would suggest that the document state that a user must be a Project Administrator, specifically, to use this feature.

Comment: @Levi Lu MSFT, are you sure about this? I can't verify this, I have a user that isn't a member of any group. I see that the only permission that affects the "Cross-repo policies" is the "Edit policies" from the Project settings --> Repos-->Repositories-> Git Repositories.  If "Edit policies" is allowed, users can modify the Cross Repo Policies.
I'm trying to find a way to disable access to "Global" policies but allow users to add "local" policies on specific repos/branches.

Comment: I can achieve what I want by denying "Edit Policies" on "Git Repositories" and allowing it on each specific repo/branch but this is something I want to avoid due to the number of repos. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require changes on specific repos/branches

Comment: Levi, I'm afraid this isn't so, to echo George: I'm a Project Administrator but this menu item isn't available to me.